# Excel 2010 switching to formula view after every click

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

Since I installed `Excel 2010 64-bit` (was using `32-bit` version before), every time I click on an icon in one of the ribbons, e.g. reducing icon size:

[image]

The top bar switches to the formula view:

[image]

This happens on every click, with every icon and is just killing my productivity.

**Any idea what the problem might be?**

FYI I'm using:
 `Office Professional Plus 2010 - SP1 - V 14.0.6023.1000 (64-bit)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you having an issue with the ribbon being hidden after you click? If so double click the 'Home'or any other button there, it won't auto hide.

Comment: That was it, I must have somehow double-clicked the ribbon some how.